# javax.xml.namespace.QName no existe en Java 11

Tags: webservice, maven, wsdl, java-11

tengo problemas al intentar ejecutar clases Java que se generaron automaticamente de un wsdl con el atributo javax.xml.namespace.QName, estaba funcionando correctamente en Java 7 pero al cambiar de versión dejó de reconocer.
pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.jstl.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
              <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
              <version>1.0-2</version>
            </dependency>   
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>           
        
        <!-- POI -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                  <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>stax</groupId>
                  <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache Commons Fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache Commons Lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Java Activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- JavaMail extension -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency> 
    </dependencies>
```

Intenté agregar exclusiones, para xml-apis pero aún así sigue sin funcionar no sé que más quitar que más agregar estoy en un bucle intento varias cosas pero no llego a la solución, en su mayoría siempre se trabajó con Java-7 pero actualmente se está realizando estos cambios en Java-11 y no puedo pasar de este punto porque el único que me genera problemas es:
javax.xml.namespace.QName
The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml

Pero en las librerías existe esa dependencia buscandolas.
Les dejo Tambien el código que se generó el cual está causando problemas quisiera saber si hay alguna solución agradecería su apoyo que ya intenté buscarle una solución durante 1 semana.

Service.java

````
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;

@WebServiceClient(name = "service", 
                  wsdlLocation = "/wsdl/wsd_creado.wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "http://camel.apache.org/cxf/jaxws/dispatch") 
public class Service extends javax.xml.ws.Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://camel.apache.org/cxf/jaxws/dispatch", "service");
    public final static QName Port = new QName("http://camel.apache.org/cxf/jaxws/dispatch", "port");
    static {
        URL url = Service.class.getResource("/wsdl/wsd_creado.wsdl");
        if (url == null) {
            url = Service.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/wsdl/wsd_creado.wsdl");
        } 
        if (url == null) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Service.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "/wsdl/wsd_creado.wsdl");
        }       
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public Service(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
    }

    public Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public Service() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }
    
    public Service(WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
    }

    public Service(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
    }

    public Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }    
    @WebEndpoint(name = "port")
    public AbsenceContingent getPort() {
        return super.getPort(Port, AbsenceContingent.class);
    }
    @WebEndpoint(name = "port")
    public AbsenceContingent getPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(Port, AbsenceContingent.class, features);
    }

}```

Si existe algún error dentro del pom.xml que se pueda corregir o es que debo modificar el código o existe otro método que tenga que cambiar en java-11 agradecería su apoyo.
````

Comment: Tú error es en compilación o ejecución? Ya que java 11 si tiene soporte para javax.xml

Comment: Te recomiendo esta duda ya que es algo similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module